# Is it possible to simplify the following combination?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

$$C(n, r-1) = \frac{(n)!}{(n - (r - 1))! (r - 1)!} $$

Could I simplify any further or break up the $(n - (r - 1))!$ part? I'm having a hard time following a problem in the book and if I could understand this it would really help out.

Comment: The question is a bit too vague to be answered usefully except by accident; it needs a bit more context. What’s the thing that you’re having a hard time following?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{n!}{(n-(r-1))!} = n (n-1) (n-2) \cdots (n-(r-1)+1)$$
and that in particular, the right hand side has $r-1$ terms. Maybe this helps?

For example, $C(10,3) = \frac{10!}{7!3!}=\frac{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8}{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}$.
This form is a little more intuitive if you "reason" through the counting: to count the number of groups of three you can form out of ten people, there are $10$ choices for the first, $9$ choices for the second, and $8$ choices for the third person, but you need to divide by $3!$ because $10\cdot 9 \cdot 8$ is the number of *ordered* teams (say, assigning them to president, vice president, and secretary), and we don't care about order.